# Load Image and Videos into Recycler View (Lag in loading Video Thumbnail)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to Load Images and Video in Same Recycler View, But the Video Preview takes about a minute to Show. How can I load it Fast? Suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Here is my onBindViewHolder:-

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Files files = filesList.get(position);

    holder.userName.setText(files.getName());
    Glide.with(context)
                .load(files.getUri())
                .into(holder.savedImage);
}
```

Files is My Model Class. I am Loading Images and Videos Using URI.

Answer (score 0):

As the glide converts the image to lower quality so sometime it may time to transform and load the same, so you can avoid the transforming of the image by adding following code to glide.

```
  Glide.with(context)
            .load(files.getUri())
            .dontTransform()
            .into(holder.savedImage);
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: I can't able to use .dontTransfrom() method.

Comment: which version of glide you are using?

Comment: Glide Version 4.0.0

Comment: compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.1' try with this, because i have used it

Comment: Will I able to Load Video Thumbnail without Lagging? from this Library.

Comment: Nope its not Working.